# How to handle error by myself while using Loguru

Tags: python, unicode, loguru

I have some sentence with custom encoded characters. when using Loguru, it raises UnicodeEncodeError because it can't encode my sentence due to those custom characters, so I hope I can handle error by myself, what should I do?

Comment: You should show some code that generates the error.  Read [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

you can wrap logger with try-except:

```
def log(message):
    try:
        loguru.logger.info(message)
    except UnicodeEncodeError:
        print('...')
```